# Hide Group Header insertion and editing mode - OpenERP7

Tags: odoo

I wonder if there is any way to hide the items that I have in the header of a form, I would like to see them in query mode only.

I know of the existence of CSS classes that allow openERP own show / hide elements, as *oe_edit_only*, *oe_save_only*, there is also the *oe_view_only* classes.

```
<form string="People" version="7.0">
    <header class="oe_view_only">
       <button string="Wait" name="button_assists" states="assigned" type="object"/>
              ....
    </header>
         ...
</from>
```

[image: hide section]

But I can not make it work in my case.

I appreciate any help.